# How can I capture the null value when I clean a Textfield on Wicket?

Tags: ajax, wicket, textfield

I'm using a textfield for a date property of my object. I've a jquery-ui datepicker for that field. The problem is the following.

When I pick a date on that field, I'm trying to capture that value within the onUpdate method of the AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior. The thing is, I'm getting the selected value the first time. However, when the user cleans the textfield I'm not getting the null value. So the value still has the old selected value, which should instead be set to null this time. The onUpdate method is not fired when the field is cleaned. I think the model of the field is not changed when the field is cleaned and that's why the onUpdate method is not fired. How can I capture the null value?

```
    surveyRandevuDatePicker = new TextField<String>("surveyRandevuDatePicker", new PropertyModel<String>(itemModel, "surveyRandevuDisplay"));

    surveyRandevuDatePicker.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onkeydown") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8745814248540998760L;

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            surveyRandevuSelectedValue = surveyRandevuDatePicker.getModelObject();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` use the [OnChangeAjaxBehavior](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/OnChangeAjaxBehavior.html)

`OnChangeAjaxBeahvior` is a subclass of `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`. I use `OnChangeAjaxBeahvior` for `TextField` and it's descendants to track all changes in the component. It works cross-browser and support ale changes in a component like cut and paste and normal editing (onkeyup, onkeydown). `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` can be used then when you want track *one* event which you select in the constructor by passing a string like you did with `"onkeydown"`

I use `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` often with the `onblur` event.

Comment: Using onChangeAjaxBehavior seems to be working. What's the difference actually? When to prefer one to another?

Comment: I updated my answer to answer your additional questions. Please accept if it was helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The thing I don't get is the following. Why does AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior NOT capture the null value, that is when the user deletes the value on the textfield. That's when the key is down, right?

Comment: Honestly i dont know. I can only guess that you should try to use `onkeyup` because in `onkeydown` the new value isn't yet passed to the component. You could also override `getUpdateModel() ` and return `Boolean.TRUE`. Could you please accept my answer?